# 1:1 NAT IP address using iptables

Tags: linux, dhcp, nat, iptables

Suppose I have 2 internal networks:
1.1.1.0/24 and 1.1.2.0/24

I would like to NAT a specific IP address from one network to the other, in which the new address would be obtained via DHCP.

For example:
1.1.1.1 --NAT--> 1.1.2.x (determined via DHCP)

Is this possible via iptables?

EDIT: Forgot to mention NAT is done by a router interfacing both networks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need NAT rather than plain routing?

Comment: No specific reason. Only experimentation and learning.

Comment: We need more data to write iptables rules. We need interface names... anyway, maybe another post resolved about this can help you [post](http://superuser.com/questions/1155069/iptables-natforwarding-setup/1155076)