# Iptables NATforwarding setup

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I have 2 Virtual machines with CentOS7:

1. Networkcard : Intern network IP `192.168.1.10` w/ GW: 192.168.1.254 enp0s3 (Client1) (NO DIRECT CONNECTION TO INTERNET)
2. Networkcard : Intern network IP `192.168.1.254` enp0s3 and NAT IP `10.0.3.15` enp0s8 (Client2) (HAS INTERNET CONNECTION) (NO GW's)

The goal is to be able to ping to for example google.com with Client1, who hasn't direct internet connection but the connection forwarded by client2.

How can I do this with iptables?

Comment: We need more data. Which gateways have both vms? which of them is doing iptables and has internet access? I guess the client2 hasn't internet access and is what you want, only to access to internet through the client1, right? we need the names of the interfaces too... Poor information here!

Comment: editted a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok is simple. You must enable forwarding on the machine that is going to do the NAT. You must do two things for this:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
and
`iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

And then masquerade for the output to internet doing:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s8 -j MASQUERADE`

We are assuming that you don't have other rules conflicting this and that the Client2 has internet access working. You can clean all rules before doing this with `iptables -F`and `iptables -t nat -F` and then launching this rules I put before.

Comment: Nice, glad to help. Don't forget mark the question as resolved :)

Comment: Ok marked it ;)

Comment: Thank you. Is a good practice... not only because the people who helped you gains reputation points... is a way to say "Thank you" and is a site rule! If is solved, mark it because maybe can help others later.